# How to fill the gap before the figure with the text after the figure in IEEEAccess?

Tags: spacing, graphics, includegraphics

I have added a figure after two sections and now figure is between the sections and there is a huge space before the figure and the second section is started after the figure. How to fix the second section before the figure to fill the gap?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please provide a MWE (Minimal Working Example) that illustrates the problem. However, my best guess right now would be that [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/) might help.

Comment: impossible to say why there is space.Have you used `[H]` ?

Comment: Actually i have added multiple figures in single figure and the 2nd column is remained blank and the next section is started in next page by itself. I want to start the section in 2nd column alongside the figure.

Comment: The figure is filing one column of the page. when i try [H], the figure is placed in after the text or other figure and half of the figure is disappeared because there is no enough space for the figure.

Comment: If it fills a column, use [p], and possibly insert it earlier in the section.